# FullCalendar - Get info range when use eventMouseEnter

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

In my case I have setup the timeline like:

```
  events: [{
     title: 'My schedule'
     start: '2021-07-08T01:00:00Z',
     end: '2021-07-08T03:00:00Z',
  }]
```

Which mean that my time `00:00UTC` will be shifted to local time `GMT+7` and `timeZone:'local'` (as default) , follow as this doc https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing

- At ui view is render timeline exactly what I want that `2021-07-08T08:00:00Z GMT+7`  & `2021-07-08T10:00:00Z GMT+7`  (Perfect).
- But when I try to get back that info with:

```
  eventMouseEnter(info) {
      console.log(info.event._instance.range);
  }
```

I get this:

```
  {
    end: Wed Jul 08 2021 15:08:10 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time) {}
    start: Wed Jul 08 2021 17:08:10 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time) {}
  }
```

Don't know why but, is seem like i get the wrong info or that info just add more `GMT+7`?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing is wrong, these times are the same. It's just that `2021-07-08T08:00:00Z` is written in UTC and `Wed Jul 08 2021 15:08:10 GMT+0700` is written using the local timezone. I'm not sure why it added some minutes and seconds though, maybe that's related to exactly where the mouse entered within the event. I haven't seen `event._instance.range` used before - normally you'd use `event.start` and `event.end`.

Comment: Check this test case: [link](https://codepen.io/kkasing11/pen/abWZdXo) (fyi).
And yes, I just figure out that the times are stored as JS Date objects which don't support timezones. After that I've try `event.start.toISOString()` and `event.end.toISOString()` follow the doc [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeZone#UTC-coercion) it's work fine now. Thanks for your time.